# Can I fail over from on cloud website to on-premise in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I came across this question in my AWS study:

> Your company is posting a big article on the front page of your
>   website tomorrow. It is expected that the demand could potentially
>   overwhelm your infrastructure. In the event of a load failure, how can
>   you set up DNS failover to a static website?

```
Options:
A.  Duplicate the exact application architecture in another region and configure DNS latency-based routing
B.  Build out additional capacity to ensure there is no scenario in which the application can fail
C.  Enable failover to an on-premise data center
D.  Use Route 53 and the failover option to failover to a static S3 website bucket or CloudFront distribution in the event of an issue
```

I wonder if C is the right option? Would it make sense if it is ok to interpret "data center" has a static website there. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think AWS will ever have "use not AWS data center" (option C) as a correct answer :-) For me option D looks correct here.

Comment: `A` doesn't make sense; `B` is hardly achievable, not to mention the cost of such solution; `C` might be doable but the answer doesn't mention how you would do that and there is nowhere mentioned that you even have a datacenter; `D` is "obviously" correct as it aligns well with AWS best practices and so called graceful degradation.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, kindly post it as an answer and I will accept

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much better option would be to use load balancer / cloud front distribution and auto scaling RDS to avoid failure at the first place.

But since thats not one of the answer, option 'D' is the nearest accurate answer.

A and B are not correct as those can also get overwhelmed when the traffic grows. Even option C, on premise can get overloaded with traffic if it's not static and cached.